# How to print array repeatedly with a specified number of times

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array for example:

`var arr = ['a','b','c','d'];`

Now I will ask user to insert a number for example: 6 or 7 or 10 or any number.

Lets take an example that user has enter: 10

Now the output should be: a b c d a b c d a b

total of 10 values should get print using the array values in order.

But the main problem is that there should be **No if condition**

Comment: You're supposed to do your own homework ;) Why don't you try to resolve it yourself and come back with specific questions?

Comment: I am not asking for the code, Just tell me the logic and also I am trying this from the last 6 hours.

Comment: And I was thinking to divide the user input into parts like: If a user input is 10, then I will divide it into 4,4,2, And will run for loop inside a for loop. But not able to divide the number without if condition.

Comment: We're suggesting that you come up with some approach and then ask more specific questions about an approach rather than just asking for a solution.

Comment: Use a counter and for loop. Use the modulo operator to get an array index from the counter.

Comment: @torazaburo recursively but with the specified number of times.

Comment: @torazaburo—no need to shout, just explain why the use of recursive is inappropriate. The title has been modified so you can delete your comments anyway.

Comment: @RobG Deleted. Shouldn't have shouted, but only did so when the OP ignored my initial comment without bothering to look up what the word actually meant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make use of the modulus operator (%). [Docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2FArithmetic_Operators#Remainder_(.25))

Pseudo code:

```
loop with index i
    output yourArray[i % yourArray.length]
end loop
```

Comment: Might want to increment the index… ;-)

Comment: Its pseudo code, s/he can figure out how to increment the index.

Comment: Appreciate for the efforts, I will try.

Answer (score 1):

Normally:

```
for (var i = 0; i < input; i++) {
  console.log(arr[i%arr.length]);
}
```

Recursively:

```
var f = function(input) {
  return input > 0 ? f(input-1)+arr[input%arr.length] : arr[0];
}

console.log(f(10));
```

Comment: You kinda have to on a recursive function, and I assume you didn't actually mean recursively. The `Normally` has no `if` and works.